# Python erro api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Tags: python, c++, dll

Uso Windows 7 64bits, baixei e instalei o python 3.5 porém ao iniciar o programa, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> O programa não pode ser iniciado porque está faltando
>   api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll no seu computador.

Já tentei baixar pacote visual c++ do Windows só que também da erro ( falha na instalação ).

Answer (score 2):

O próprio erro já fala que está faltando o arquivo `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`, ele é instalado com uma atualização do Windows.

Passos:

- Instalar o [Service Pack 1 para Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/976932/information-about-service-pack-1-for-windows-7-and-for-windows-server-2008-r2).
- Baixar e instalar a atualização. Veja como fazer isso nesse: [Atualização para o Universal C Runtime no Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)

Comment: Meu windows já possui o service pack 1. Já tentei baixar e instalar a atualização mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Alguma sugestão a mais ?

Comment: @YanAquino. Vê se esse [link](http://www.solvusoft.com/pt-br/files/inexistente-n%C3%A3o-encontrada-erro/dll/windows/microsoft/windows-8-pro/api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0-dll/) te ajuda

Comment: Na instalação do programa, meu byteFence Anti-Malware encontrou riscos nessa instalação. O que devo fazer ? @Taisbevalle

Comment: Entrei no link que voce me mandou, baixei o programa, executei-o, rodei a limpeza dele só que mesmo assim continuou dando o erro ao tentar abrir o python.

Comment: Desativa o antivírus

Comment: O erro continua. Continuei a instalação mesmo dando aviso de perigo. Porem no término do escaneamento do programa, o python continuou com o erro ao abrir.

Comment: @YanAquino, você executou todos os passos desse [link](http://www.solvusoft.com/pt-br/files/inexistente-n%C3%A3o-encontrada-erro/dll/windows/microsoft/windows-8-pro/api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0-dll/)?

Comment: Sim, cada passo a passo... Já não sei mais o que vai resolver esse problema.